# PyQT5 Slide up|down effect for video

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

i need make slide down/up effect for foreground video on PyQt5. Some thing like that no slide effect. Why?
For the QLabel this code work well, but for QVideoWidget not.

I try change position with move() - the same.

```
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(QMainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        self.resize(1920, 1080)
        self.setFixedWidth(1920)
        self.setFixedHeight(1080)
        self.setAutoFillBackground(False)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.mediaPlayer = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.videoWidget = QVideoWidget(self)
        self.videoWidget.setGeometry(0,0, 1920, 1080)
        self.mediaPlayer.setVideoOutput(self.videoWidget)
        self.mediaPlayer.setMedia(QMediaContent(QUrl.fromLocalFile('/video.mp4')))

        self.up_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.up_btn.setText('UP')
        self.up_btn.move(0,50)
        self.up_btn.clicked.connect(self.slide_up)

        self.up_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self)
        self.up_btn.setText('DOWN')
        self.up_btn.clicked.connect(self.slide_down)

    def slide_up(self):
        self.mediaPlayer.stop()

        self.video_block_anim_up = QPropertyAnimation(self.videoWidget, b"pos")
        self.video_block_anim_up.setStartValue(1080)
        self.video_block_anim_up.setEndValue(0)
        self.video_block_anim_up.setDuration(300)
        self.video_block_anim_up.start()


    def slide_down(self):
        self.mediaPlayer.stop()
        self.video_block_anim = QPropertyAnimation(self.videoWidget, b"pos")
        self.video_block_anim.setStartValue(0)
        self.video_block_anim.setEndValue(1080)
        self.video_block_anim.setDuration(300)
        self.video_block_anim.start()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Could you explain better, what it means: *For the QLabel this code work well, but for QVideoWidget not.*

Comment: Yes, sure. If I use QLabel as a block to which I apply animation, then the animation works fine, the block moves out from the bottom and moves back in. If I use a QVideoWidget as a block that I want to move, then this movement does not occur.